# Indicate corresponding author with bibtex using bibitem or bibliography

Tags: bibtex

I have my CV in latex, where I list publications using bibtex and each entry using `\bibitem`. I want to indicate the corresponding author in all the papers.

A MWE is below

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem
\makeatother
\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem
\nobibliography{mypublications}
\endgroup

\section*{\textbf{Publications}}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \bibentry{PhysRevLett.117.238004}
\end{itemize}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

The mypublications.bib is

```
@article{PhysRevLett.117.238004,
  title = {Mutation at Expanding Front of Self-Replicating Colloidal Clusters},
  author = {Tanaka, Hidenori and Zeravcic, Zorana and Brenner, Michael P.},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume = {117},
  issue = {23},
  pages = {238004},
  numpages = {5},
  year = {2016},
  month = {Dec},
  publisher = {American Physical Society},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.238004},
  url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.117.238004}
}
```

As it is, it produces the following text

• Hidenori Tanaka, Zorana Zeravcic, and Michael P. Brenner. Mutation at expanding front of self-replicating colloidal clusters. Phys. Rev. Lett., 117:238004, Dec 2016

Let's say that the last author is the corresponding author for this paper. I would like to have a "sign" on that author, e.g.,

• Hidenori Tanaka, Zorana Zeravcic, and Michael P. Brenner{^T}. Mutation at expanding front of self-replicating colloidal clusters. Phys. Rev. Lett., 117:238004, Dec 2016

Now, the easiest thing to do is to modify the .bib file to indicate this. But I want to have the flexibility of changing the "sign" from within tex file, and be able to use the bib file with other tex files which do not indicate the corresponding author. This would need definition of a new field in the bib file, and modification of the bst file. Can you guide me on how to achieve this? I am thinking along the lines of modifying the name format conditionally (which I am doing for my own name). There might be other solutions.

Comment: At the moment too much guess work would be involved to answer this question effectively. It is not even clear what 'indicate' means. (Bold? purple? blinking?) Please provide a minimal amount of code that illustrates where you are and further explanation of where you want to end up. Note that this 'minimal amount of code' should be complete, but minimal *TeX document that others can compile for themselves; in LaTeX, that meanst it starts with `\documentclass` and  goes all the way to `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please indicate what you mean by "best", or even "good", in the context of your query. Separately, is anything stopping you from attaching something like `${}^*$` to selected surnames?

Comment: @jon I added MWE and more information. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: How do you envision marking this? Imagine there are 30 entries with different 'sets' of authors. How would the user indicate (at any level) which the corresponding authors are? It seems to me that you must mark the author somehow in each entry, and unless it is the same name each time, there is no good 'automatic' solution. (Note also that if you use not BibTeX, but Biber and `biblatex`, you will have more flexibility.)

Comment: I was thinking maybe I could define a new field in each bib file that has either the name of corresponding author or the place of the corresponding author in the author list (for example, 1 if the first author is the corresponding author, 2 if the second, and -1 if the last). I can see that it might not be easy to implement though.